# Bootstrap tabs not switching with next button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to switch tabs wih next and previous button, but when I click on the button, the content of the are switching well but not the "active tabs". 
Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZazaAngular/a5ed16ma/2/

```
<div class="container">
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
        <li  id="tab2"><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li id="tab3"><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
               <div class="row form-group">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#orange">
                   <span class="icon-arrow-next"></span> Next</button>
               </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
               <div class="row form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#yellow">
                  <span class="icon-arrow-next"></span> Next</button>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

you have to do something like this

Here is your working code : http://www.bootply.com/120472
or this code http://jsfiddle.net/4ns0mdcf/

HTML :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
 $('.btnNext').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I'm new on bootstrap and angular2, do you know how to write your javascript code on typescript please ?

Comment: @ZazaAngular - since this answers works, you should mark it accepted. Converting the js to ts is a separate issue.

Comment: Sorry, I marked accepted too fast, I updated my fiddle with this answer but it doesn't work as well :-/  http://jsfiddle.net/ZazaAngular/a5ed16ma/3/         Maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

#### In Bootstrap 4, the `active` class is placed inside the `a` tag, instead of the `li` tag (as in Bootstrap 3).

Tab example in Bootstrap 3:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">  <!-- active class is an attribute of the <li> element! -->
    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Tab example in Bootstrap 4:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab">Tab 1</a>
    <!-- active class is an attribute of the <a> element! -->
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs for details.

Thus, the JS needs to be adjusted for correct DOM traversal. Using jQuery, one can select all buttons with the `btn-next` class and set a click event that traverses the DOM to the next tab and triggers a click on it.

JS:

```
$('.btn-next').click(function() {
  $('.nav-item > .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

HTML for Button:

```
<button class="btn-next">Next</button>
```

I saw a similar solution on Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/dPkMlefHpl

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well noted. I was looking at v4 bootstrap tutorial instead of v3, which my project uses.